# Unterschied zwischen »Pasta« und »Paste«

Tags: difference, word-choice, regional

Ich finde in meinem Wahrig diese zwei Varianten: *Pasta* und *Paste,* und zwar mit ungefähr derselben Bedeutung. Sind die Wörter einigermaßen austauschbar? Pasta als Lebensmittel heißt wohl nur *Pasta,* das versteh ich.

Ich habe an einer Stelle *Schleifpasta* geschrieben; ein Deutscher (aus Nordbayern) hat mich korrigiert und *Schleifpaste* geschrieben.
*Zahnpasta* hab ich gelernt, aber das Wörterbuch schlägt auch *Zahnpaste* vor.

Ist dies regional bedingt oder gibt es Regeln, wann man das eine oder das andere verwenden kann?

Comment: Ich bin auch aus Nordbayern und würde außer bei Zahnpasta eigentlich immer mit past**e** zusammensetzen.

Comment: @guidot Könnte dies eine art Vokalharmonie sein??? Dies gibt es ja eigentlich im Deutschen nicht, aber vielleicht liegen die Laute halt so besser im Munde?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

»Pasta« und übrigens auch »Kassa« sind regionale Varianten von »Paste« und »Kasse«, bedeuten aber genau dasselbe, wenn man mal davon absieht, dass es zu »Pasta« auch ein Homonym mit der Bedeutung »Nudeln« gibt. Pasta und Kassa trifft man eher im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums an, Paste und Kasse eher im Norden.

Zahnpasta scheint aber im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum üblich zu sein, wobei in nördlicheren Regionen zudem auch die Zahnpaste akzeptiert ist. (In Österreich würde niemand von einer Zahnpaste sprechen.)

Es gibt auch einen zeitlichen Wandel: Früher (vor mehr als 50 Jahren) dürfte die Pasta weiter verbreitet gewesen sein als die Paste. Davon zeugt z.B. eine Stangenpast**a**, die noch immer in einem etwas antiquierten Design vertreiben wird. (Wer sich mit einem Rasiermesser rasiert, schärft es mit einem Streichriemen. Damit dieser Riemen gut schärft, muss man ihn mit einer Pasta behandeln, die in Stangenform verkauft wird.)

[image]

Da die Herstellerfirma Firma Giesen & Forsthoff in Solingen, also nicht grade im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums liegt, glaube ich, dass die Pasta früher auch weiter im Norden noch üblich war, und dass die Paste von Norden kommend langsam die Pasta verdrängt.

Comment: Und wieder etwas gelernt. War gerade am Schreiben meiner Antwort à la »*Pasta* gilt nur für *Zahnpasta*« und dann dies. So hab ich zum Glück noch überall »in Deutschland« einfügen können.

Answer (score 5):

Sowohl *Paste* als auch *Pasta* wurden von dem selben lateinischen Wortstamm *pasta* entlehnt, das seinerseits auf das griechische *πάστη* (*pástē*) zurückgeht; die Bedeutung des mittellateinischen *pasta* war *Teig, Brei*, später wurde es auf die entsprechende Nudelsorte konkretisiert. (Quelle: [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=pasta))

Im heutigen in Deutschland gesprochenem Deutsch hat die Variante Pasta – von der *Zahnpasta* als Sonderfall abgesehen – ausschließlich die Bedeutung *Nudeln*. Das gilt auch für Bayern, bis an die österreichische Grenze heran. Wahrscheinlich ist die Sprachgrenze hier ähnlich scharf wie *Kassa* versus *Kasse*, was Hubert als Beispiel angebracht hat. Es wird dich also kein Deutscher sofort verstehen, wenn du *Pasta* sagst aber »eine breiige, teigige oder vergleichbare Masse« meinst; man würde erst einmal an Nudeln denken.

Und noch ein, zwei Wörter zum Sonderfall *Zahnpasta:* Das Zeug aus der Tube für auf die Zahnbürste kann auch *Zahnpaste* genannt werden. Wenn der Zahnarzt oder der Kieferorthopäde einen Gebissabdruck machen möchte, wird er auch eine Art *Zahn-Paste* (korrekte Bezeichnung: [*Alginat*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algins%C3%A4ure)) benutzen. Letztere kann aber nicht durch *Zahnpasta* ersetzt werden. *Zahnpaste* wäre also prinzipiell mehrdeutig, *Zahnpasta* ist es in Deutschland nicht.

---

Nebenbemerkung zur österreichischen *Kassa*: Im Gegensatz zu *Pasta* existiert dieses Wort im in Deutschland gesprochenen Deutsch nicht. Durch regen Tourismus nach Österreich ist ein gewisses Hintergrundverständnis entstanden, dass »die Kasse in Österreich seltsam geschrieben wird.« Beide Gründe helfen, dass *Kassa* viel eher verstanden wird als *Pasta* es würde.

Comment: Dies ist sehr interessant. In meinem Duden "Wie sagt man in Österreich?" steht überhaupt nichts von Pasta/Paste, über Kassa/Kasse aber schon.

Comment: @Beta Wie ich unter Huberts Antwort geschrieben habe, war mir schlicht nicht bewusst, dass *Pasta* eine andere Bedeutung in Österreich hat. Ich denke, da dürfte es vielen anderen ähnlich gehen … Es sei denn, das Buch wurde von Österreichern geschrieben. In dem Fall haben sie wahrscheinlich schlicht nicht gewusst, dass die Form in Deutschland so nicht existiert. Oder aber es war weniger relevant, denn wie oft kommt Otto Normalpiefke schon mit *Pasta* in Kontakt, die keine *Zahnpasta* ist? ;)

Comment: @guidot Aha, das hat auch einen anderen Namen. Wieder was gelernt ;) (Habs in die Antwort eingebaut.)

Answer (score 3):

Dieser Frage wendet sich auch dieser Beitrag [zu Zahnpasta](https://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/19146/sbj/zahnpasta/) auf Korrekturen.de zu. Wie er erklärt, wurden Paste und Pasta bis Mitte des 20. Jhd. Synonym verwendet. Dafür sprechen auch das von Herrn Schölnast gelieferte Bildmaterial und der Duden-Eintrag zu Pasta:

> 1. (selten) Paste
> 2. [italienisch pasta, Paste] italienische Bezeichnung für: Teigwaren ;

sowie endlich das Vorhandensein eines Duden-Eintrages für Zahnpaste!

Anscheinend ist "Paste", die treuere Ableitung aus dem Griechischen, schon lange populärer, denn das Grimm'sche [Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GP01175#XGP01175) nennt nur diese Form.

Zu der Frage, wieso man nun gerade bei Zahnanpasta die lateinische Form wählt, sagt der eingangs zitierte Artikel:

> *Im Kompositum "Zahnpasta" hat sich die "Pasta" in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung von "Paste" aber noch erhalten, was sicher auch auf den Einklang der drei "a"-Silben zurückzuführen ist.*

Comment: Also in "Zahnpasta" sei doch eine Vokalharminie vorhanden, wie ich im Kommentar ganz oben vorgeschlagen hab

Comment: @Beta ja, das meint der Autor des Artikels auch.